# Laravel CRUD Delete function error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud, delete-file

Here,what i want is when i press delete button necessary raw need to be deleted.that means relevant trainee_id and its details need to be deleted.

[image]
Here is the controller i`m using for that.

```
public function admin_destroy($trainee_id)
{
    registerdetails::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->first()->destroy(); 
}
```

Here is the route.

```
Route::get('Delete/{trainee_id?}', 'UserRegisterController@admin_destroy')
       ->where('trainee_id', '(.*)');;`
```

Here is the view button for delete.

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="Delete/{{ $item->trainee_id }}">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Here is the URL um getting when i press the delete button.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delete/MOB/TR/1739`

Finally this the error i`m getting.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me to fix this error.

Comment: You are sending 3 parameters to url, it should be only one as you mentioned in route 

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Delete/MOB/TR/1739`

Comment: What is line 196 of UserRegisterController? Also, your IDs have forward slashes in them which is going to be problematic in the URL, you'll need to handle them properly.

Comment: You have to send three params to url Or change `href="Delete/{{ $item->trainee_id }}"` to `href="Delete/MOB/TR/{{ $item->trainee_id }}"` in `a` tag!

Comment: @PankajMakwana, it looks like MOB/TR/1739 altogether is a single value which is the trainee_id he is trying

Comment: You can try replacing `/` with another character in `MOB/TR/1739` and again replace another character with `/` on controller
SO string should be `MOB##TR##1739` and then replace `##` with `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function admin_destroy($trainee_id)
    {
        registerdetails::destroy($trainee_id)->first(); 
    }
```

use this

Answer (score 1):

`destroy` method expects a key, or array of keys. Like so:

```
registerdetails::destroy($trainee_id);
```

You can also do:

```
registerdetails::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->delete();
```

Check the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 1):

the `destroy()` function needs a parameter (either a single id or array of ids or ids seprated by comma) to be passed as

```
App\registerdetails::destroy(1);

App\registerdetails::destroy([1, 2, 3]);

App\registerdetails::destroy(1, 2, 3);
```

either pass the `id` to the destroy like this

```
registerdetails::destroy($trainee_id);
```

or use `delete()` method to delete as

```
registerdetails::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->delete();
```